# Set up a recurrence relation for the algorithm’s basic operation count and solve it

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

Consider the following algorithm

```
ALGORITHM Find(A[0..n‐1])
    if n ==1 return A[0]
    else temp = Find(A[0..n‐2])
    if temp ≤ A[n‐1] return temp
    else return A[n‐1]

a. What does this algorithm compute?
b. Set up a recurrence relation for the algorithm’s basic operation count and solve it.
```

Does this algo return A[0],A[0..3],A[0..5],A[0.7],A[0..8], perhaps for n=9? Am I on the right track?

Appreciate if someone could give me along!
Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the cost of the slicing operation `A[0..n-2]`. Does it make a copy of the input, or just a reference with new start/end points?

Comment: it should be the copy of the inputs

Comment: Is that the exact way the algorithm was given to you? May we have some context and a run-down on the notation you are using?

Comment: That's the question given, yeap its just whatever I have there..

Comment: What about the notation? e.g. A[].. an array? Because my default reading of it doesn't make sense. also make sure you use @ infront of my username so that I see your response. Why is it called Find as well? ... I guess I'm just trying to get any additional information about this problem.

Comment: This smells a lot like a homework problem. What have you tried? It looks like you took some wild guesses at the answer which you wrote below the question. Can you provide what you thought process is, and what in particular you are struggling with?

Comment: my problem is I ain't sure if my thoughts are right. Basically,for n=9, it will go to temp, since A[0..7], so it calls itself again, with n being 7 now, and then to A[0..5] and down. then after reaching A[0..1], it will return A[0], and subsequently the other values.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm will recursively calculate the *minimum* of the given array or list of elements.

For every value of `n`. You calculate he minimum of all values preceding `n`(ie. <= n - 1). If the value returned is less than the `value[n]`, you return that value else you return `value[n]`.

The base case is trivial when you have only one element. You return that value as the minimum.